# create a layer to return images from a postgis DB

Tags: geoserver

I'd like to identify a solution to create a WMS layer in geoserver that returns an image stored in the DB (postgis) projected (moved, scaled and rotated) to specific coordinates.

In the DB I store the house floor plans as jpeg and I need to rotate, scale, move those image to a given latitude and longitude so that I can overlap to OSM map in open layer.

Comment: Does this have to be done with openlayers?  It would be fairly easy to overlay the OSM map with the image using QGIS.

Comment: do you have the real world location of the images stored somewhere? otherwise you need to look into georeferencing them first

Answer (score 0):

Yes my web app is based on openlayer, my collegue succeeded in trasforing the image (traslate, rotate, resize) in openlayer, but I think it should be performed on the backend that is postgis+geoserver

My images are stored as jpeg (or raster) in the postgis, but I do not know how geoserver can read them directly from the DB and transform them based on some parameters.

Thank you
Federico